# latest version of oracle developer including forms and reports

Tags: oracle

What is the latest version of Oracle Developer which includes Oracle Forms and Reports?

I am taking a Database Administration class in college.  The professor is installing Oracle Developer 6i but I want the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

First off, are you really sure that you want to use a different version of the tool than your professor is using?  Oracle Forms and Reports were completely rearchitected in the more recent version to run in a three-tier environment rather than building client-server applications as was done in Forms 6i.  That is going to make it very difficult for you to follow along with what the professor is doing.

The most recent version of Developer Suite is [Developer Suite 10.1.2.0.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/downloads/index.html) which you can download from OTN.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to keep this as informational and brief as possible - I've worked with Oracle Forms/Reports for the past 3 years now.

Oracle Forms & Reports 10.1.2.0.2 is not the latest version. To go even further, Oracle Forms and Reports (including developer suite) 6i and 10gR2 are de-supported versions of Oracle Forms and Reports - 10gR2 has been de-supported since December 2011.

The latest and greatest version of Oracle Forms and Reports 11gR2 (11.1.2). There are currently two supported versions: 11gR1 (11.1.1.2 - 11.1.1.6) and 11gR2 (11.1.2). Oracle is working on a new release 12c - release date has not been confirmed but we're expecting it to come out in Q4 2012 or Q1 2013.

It is important to note that Oracle Forms has had major changes since 6i. Many built-in's are either deprecated or updated and the services infrastructure has changed. 6i is predominantly client-server based, whereas 10g and 11g releases are 3-Tier oriented (Client - Forms/Reports Application Server - Database Server). 10g Application Servers was deployed via (now dead) Oracle Application Server. For all 11g Forms and Reports releases, they are deployed via Oracle WebLogic Server (Formally BEA WebLogic Server).

If you're looking to install latest and greatest - look into 11gR2 (You'll need to download and install WebLogic 10.3.5 and Forms/Reports 11.1.2). (Its a much easier install than 11gR1):

1. Download and Install WebLogic 10.3.5: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-main-097127.html
2. Download and Install Forms 11.1.2: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/downloads/index.html

If you have any questions, let me know. Hope this helps!

If you're curious about the transition from 6i to 11g (most common topic with Forms/Reports), i put my link below, we have plenty of white papers, presentations, and videos on the subject :)

Thank you,

Gavin

http://www.pitss.com